# How to move TabularX table to top of page?

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

I've made a column-width table in TabularX and want to position it at the top of the page, but haven't found an answer on how to do it – is there a way?

```
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
   \begin{tabularx} {\columnwidth} {
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X |}
 \hline
 \makecell{Planet\\} & \makecell{Mass\\(M\textsubscript{s})} & \makecell{SMA\\(AU)} & \makecell{TA\\(\textdegree)} \\
 \hline
 b  & 0.003  & 70 & 153  \\
 \hline
 c  & 0.004  & 38.9 & 48  \\
 \hline
 d  & 0.005  & 25.6 & 292  \\
\hline
e  & 0.008  & 14.4 & 327  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Parameters calculated using figs 2 and 3.}
    \label{Table 1}
\end{center}
```

Comment: change `center` to `table` for the outer environment

Comment: unrelated but avoid doing using numbers in labels such as ``\label{Table 1}`  it's a valid label and will work but is confusing when you read the source and this is table 3 but has internal identfier `Table 1`

Comment: Also I would not use `\centering` for numeric tables it will spoil the decimal alignment unnless all entries have the same width (as in your 2nd column)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I can get the table in the desired position using this, but can I make it the width of my column (2-column doc) (which was why I was using TabularX, as something I saw on here suggested that)?

Comment: Changing center to table will have no effect on the formating of the tabularx which will still be one column wide.

Answer (score 2):

To force LaTeX to typeset the `tabularx` material at the top of a column, place the material in a `table` environment, not a `center` environment. Note that since the width of the `tabularx` environment is set to `\columnwidth`, no explicit `\centering` instruction is needed.

Do also give consideration to @David Carlisle's suggestion to align the numbers in the three data columns on their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers. And, do try to give the table a more open and inviting "look" by getting rid of all vertical rules and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules. The applications of both suggestions are displayed in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,makecell,dcolumn,booktabs,lipsum}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
% handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}  % without vertical rules
\newcommand\mD[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C|}{#1}} % with vertical rules
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % filler text

\begin{table}[t]
%\footnotesize  % not needed

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{
 | *{4}{C|} }
 \hline
 \makecell{Planet\\} & 
 \makecell{Mass\\(M\textsubscript{s})} & 
 \makecell{SMA\\(AU)} & 
 \makecell{TA\\(\textdegree)} \\
 \hline
 b  & 0.003  & 70   & 153  \\
 \hline
 c  & 0.004  & 38.9 &  48  \\
 \hline
 d  & 0.005  & 25.6 & 292  \\
 \hline
 e  & 0.008  & 14.4 & 327  \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{OP's original version}
\label{table:parameters1}

\bigskip
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{
 | >{\centering}X | d{1.3} | d{2.1} | d{3.0} |}
 \hline
 Planet & 
 \mD{\makecell{Mass\\(M\textsubscript{s})}} & 
 \mD{\makecell{SMA\\(AU)}} & 
 \mD{\makecell{TA\\(\textdegree)}} \\
 \hline
 b  & 0.003  & 70   & 153  \\
 \hline
 c  & 0.004  & 38.9 &  48  \\
 \hline
 d  & 0.005  & 25.6 & 292  \\
 \hline
 e  & 0.008  & 14.4 & 327  \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Numbers aligned on decimal markers}
\label{table:parameters2}

\bigskip
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{
 @{} >{\centering}X d{1.3} d{2.1} d{3.0} @{}}
 \toprule
 Planet & 
 \mC{\makecell{Mass\\(M\textsubscript{s})}} & 
 \mC{\makecell{SMA\\(AU)}} & 
 \mC{\makecell{TA\\(\textdegree)}} \\
 \midrule
 b  & 0.003  & 70   & 153  \\
 c  & 0.004  & 38.9 &  48  \\
 d  & 0.005  & 25.6 & 292  \\
 e  & 0.008  & 14.4 & 327  \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Numbers aligned on decimal markers, no vertical rules, fewer but well-spaced horizontal rules}
\label{table:parameters3}

\end{table}

\lipsum[2-4] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your contributions, I have managed to get it how I wanted :)